# Error (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

Quiero ingresar

```
ALTER TABLE productos ADD FOREIGN KEY (usuarioID) REFERENCES usuarios(usuarioID);
```

Para agregar una llave foránea, pero me aparece este error. Ya leí otros casos, pero ninguno me lo resuelve, y por eso pregunto.

No se si tenga que ver que existan ya estas foráneas, las cuales ingresaron sin problema

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD FOREIGN KEY (regionID) REFERENCES region(regionID);

ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD FOREIGN KEY (comunaID) REFERENCES comuna(comunaID);

ALTER TABLE productos ADD FOREIGN KEY (categoriaProductoID) REFERENCES categoriaProductos(productoID);
```

Las tablas relacionadas son:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
    productoID int,
    nombre text,
    marca text,
    precioCompra int,
    precioVenta int,
    categoriaProductoID int,
    usuarioID int
);

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    usuarioID int, 
    rut varchar(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre text,
    apellido text,
    email text,
    direccion text,
    regionID int,
    comunaID int,
    contrasena text
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que puedas crear una clave ajena a partir de un campo de otra tabla, éste último debe estar indexado. Es suficiente con sea de tipo `INDEX`, no es necesario que sea `UNIQUE` ni `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD INDEX(usuarioID);
```

Tiene su lógica pues, si tienes que asegurarte de que los datos que introduzcas en `productos.usuarioID` existan previamente en `usuarios`, los localizarás mucho más rápido si están previamente ordenados. Imagínate lo que podrían tardar las búsquedas y, en consecuencia, las inserciones, de no ser así.

Te envío el código completo para facilitar las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
  productoID int,
  nombre text,
  marca text,
  precioCompra int,
  precioVenta int,
  categoriaProductoID int,
  usuarioID int
);

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
  usuarioID int,
  rut varchar(12) PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre text,
  apellido text,
  email text,
  direccion text,
  regionID int,
  comunaID int,
  contrasena text
);

ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD INDEX(usuarioID);
ALTER TABLE productos ADD FOREIGN KEY (usuarioID) 
  REFERENCES usuarios(usuarioID);
```

Comment: Gracias David !!! era el INDEX lo que me faltaba. Todo debido a que había confundido eso con el auto_increment. Ya que la petición era asignar al usuario el ID autoincrement, y el rut como primary key, lo cual no me dejaba hacer ambas.

Comment: Para que pueda ser `AUTO_INCREMENT` necesariamente debe ser `PRIMARY KEY`. Lo que puedes hacer con `rut` es asignarle un índice `UNIQUE` y no admitir nulos `NOT NULL` que, a todos los efectos, será como un `PRIMARY KEY`